# I am getting a wrong answer for the linear equation solving by matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse

```
>> K=[6,31,221;31,221,1801;221,1801,15665]

K =

       6          31         221
      31         221        1801
     221        1801       15665

>> f=[31;197;1543]

f =

      31
     197
    1543

>> lambda=inv(K)*f

lambda =

2.1413
0.5472
0.0054
```

I even use K\f option. But it gives the same result. But this is not correct right? the correct answer should be lambda =
                                 2.1728
                                 0.6070
                                -0.0102

Comment: How did you determine the correct answer?

Comment: And did you check that you don't have any typos in your `K` and `f`?

Comment: `K*lambda-f` gives gives a result of size 10^-11. I am quite interested to learn how you came up with the other answer since that seems to be incorrect.

Comment: yes.but i dont knw if i am wrong. when i take the inv of K and multiply it with f it gives me the answer i have put. Can you please check it by directly multiplying the inversed matrix of K with f?

Comment: Lesson learned - Make sure you include as many digits of precision as possible when dealing with floating point operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got this!

To get the other (wrong) answer, I think you did:

```
>> K=[6,31,221;31,221,1801;221,1801,15665];

>> inv(K)

ans =

1.5647   -0.6276    0.0501
-0.6276    0.3235   -0.0283
0.0501   -0.0283    0.0026

>> iK=[  1.5647   -0.6276    0.0501;
-0.6276    0.3235   -0.0283;
0.0501   -0.0283    0.0026];

>> f=[31;197;1543];

>> iK*f

ans =

2.1728
0.6070
-0.0102
```

This does not work because when you manually copied the value of inv(K), you did not take the exact value computed by matlab (which is not exact anyway but close enough) instead you took the values displayed, so with only 4 digits accuracy!

Comment: thank u. I thought that may be the reason though but the last value of the ans comes from my way is negative but matlab gives a positive value. Can it has a big difference like that?

Comment: if you have an error `e` on `x`, you'll have an error `2e` on `2x` no matter the value of `x` and for instance an error `e` on `x+y` no matter the value of `x` and `y`, but now try to see what happens for `1/x`... if you have `1/(x-e)` instead of `1/x`, it can make a huge difference .. depending on the value of `x`. this is not a real proof, just a hint to show you a small error can translate into a big error, mainly because inverting a matrix is not a linear operation (whereas addition and multiplication are linear operations)

Answer (score 3):

So let's check if it's MATLAB that doesn't know how to do matrix operations. If `lambda = inv(K)*f`, then `K*lambda = f`. Is this correct?

```
lambda = K\f
lambda =
       2.1413
      0.54725
     0.005374

K*lambda
ans =
           31
          197
         1543
```

Let's see what we get if we assume that `lambda = [2.1728; 0.6070; -0.0102]` is correct:

```
f = K*lambda
f =
         29.6
       183.13
       1413.6
```

I would put my money on MATLAB being correct.

Comment: yes.but i dont knw if i am wrong. when i take the inv of K and multiply it with f it gives me the answer i have put. Can you please check it by directly multiplying the inversed matrix of K with f?

Answer (score 1):

[computation on wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e7rv5endrsp)

wolfram alpha agrees with MATLAB,...2  against 1. Do you actually have a reason for believing that the result should be different?

[image: computation on wolfram alpha]

Comment: Interesting. I would put a screenshot or something more visual to support your answer; since now it looks a bit dry and would not be valid if the link is broken somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Also: You might want to use the hyperlink functionality when using long links. It improves the readability =)

Comment: yes.but i dont knw if i am wrong. when i take the inv of K and multiply it with f it gives me the answer i have put. Can you please check it by directly multiplying the inversed matrix of K with f?

Comment: did u find what's the problem? may there is something wrong with my logic. but can't figure it out by myself

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i={{1.5647%2C-0.6276%2C0.0501}%2C+{-0.6276%2C+0.3235%2C+-0.0283}%2C+{0.0501%2C+-0.0283%2C+0.0026}}+.{{31}%2C{197}%2C{1543}}}  @ yoh.lej check this out

Comment: I found your mistake, check my other answer